# Why is this SQL generating a temporary table and running so slow?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following SQL generated from my Rails app, it is trying to get a list of all auto models that have live adverts in a marketplace app & from mysql:

```
SELECT `models`.* FROM `models` 
  INNER JOIN `autos` ON autos.model_id = models.id 
  INNER JOIN `ads` ON `ads`.id = `autos`.ad_id 
WHERE (ads.ad_status_id = 4 AND pub_start_date < NOW() AND pub_end_date > NOW() AND models.manufacturer_id = 50 ) 
GROUP BY models.id ORDER BY models.name;
```

When I run an explain, this is what I get:

```
Id  1   1   1
Select Type SIMPLE  SIMPLE  SIMPLE
Table   models  autos   ads
Type    ref ref eq_ref
Possible Keys   PRIMARY,manufacturer_id model_id,ad_id  PRIMARY,quick_search,ad_status_id
Key manufacturer_id model_id    PRIMARY
Key Length  5   4   4
Ref const   concept_development.models.id   concept_development.autos.ad_id
Rows    70  205 1
Extra   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    Using where Using where
```

I cannot understand why the query is generating a temporary table / using file-sort - all of the referenced keys are indexes. Been trying to figure this out for a few days now and getting nowhere.

Any help is very much appreciated!

EXPLAIN models:

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| manufacturer_id     | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vehicle_category_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
| synonym_names       | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

SHOW INDEXES FROM models:

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| models |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id                  | A         |        2261 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| models |          1 | manufacturer_id     |            1 | manufacturer_id     | A         |         205 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| models |          1 | vehicle_category_id |            1 | vehicle_category_id | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

MODEL TABLE STATUS:

```
+--------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name   | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time          | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+--------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| models | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 2261 |             26 |       61000 | 281474976710655 |        84992 |         0 |           2751 | 2010-09-28 18:42:45 | 2010-09-28 18:42:45 | 2010-09-28 18:44:00 | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+--------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

EXPLAIN ADS

```
+------------------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                     | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10)                  | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| fp_urn           | int(10)                  | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| user_id          | int(10)                  | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| ad_status_id     | int(3) unsigned          | NO   | MUL | 1                   |                |
| style_id         | int(10)                  | NO   |     | 3                   |                |
| search_tags      | varchar(255)             | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| title            | varchar(255)             | NO   |     |                     |                |
| description      | text                     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| currency         | enum('EUR','GBP')        | NO   |     | EUR                 |                |
| price            | decimal(8,2)             | NO   | MUL | 0.00                |                |
| proposal_type    | enum('Offered','Wanted') | NO   |     | Offered             |                |
| category_id      | int(10)                  | YES  |     | 0                   |                |
| contact          | varchar(50)              | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| area_id          | int(10)                  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| origin_id        | int(10)                  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| reject_reason_id | int(3)                   | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| date_created     | timestamp                | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| last_modified    | timestamp                | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| pub_start_date   | datetime                 | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| pub_end_date     | datetime                 | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| bumped_up_date   | datetime                 | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| state            | smallint(6)              | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| eproofed         | tinyint(1)               | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| is_featured      | int(1)                   | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| num_featured_imp | int(10)                  | YES  |     | 0                   |                |
| num_direct_imp   | int(10)                  | YES  |     | 0                   |                |
| is_top_listed    | int(1)                   | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| delta            | tinyint(1)               | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| ext_ref_id       | varchar(50)              | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| email_seller     | tinyint(1)               | YES  |     | 1                   |                |
| sort_by          | int(10)                  | YES  |     | 8                   |                |
| permalink        | varchar(500)             | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| external_url     | varchar(255)             | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+------------------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM concept_development WHERE NAME LIKE 'ads';

```
+------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options                                  | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
| ads  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 656350 |            232 |   152748032 |               0 |     87736320 | 340787200 |        1148382 | 2010-09-29 09:55:46 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL | checksum=1 delay_key_write=1 row_format=DYNAMIC |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

SHOW INDEXES FROM ADS

```
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| ads   |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id           | A         |      521391 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | NewIndex1 |            1 | ad_status_id | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | NewIndex1 |            2 | pub_end_date | A         |      260695 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | NewIndex1 |            3 | category_id  | A         |      521391 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | NewIndex1 |            4 | style_id     | A         |      521391 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | NewIndex2 |            1 | user_id      | A         |      130347 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | NewIndex3 |            1 | price        | A         |        7667 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | contact   |            1 | contact      | A         |      260695 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ads   |          1 | fp_urn    |            1 | fp_urn       | A         |      521391 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

EXPLAIN autos

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | Null | Key | Default     | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id                | int(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | NO   | PRI | NULL        | auto_increment |
| ad_id             | int(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | YES  | MUL | NULL        |                |
| style_id          | int(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | YES  | MUL | NULL        |                |
| manufacturer_id   | int(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | NO   | MUL | NULL        |                |
| model_id          | int(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | NO   | MUL | NULL        |                |
| registration      | varchar(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| year              | int(4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| fuel_type         | enum('Petrol','Diesel')                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | NO   |     | Petrol      |                |
| colour            | varchar(75)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| mileage           | varchar(25)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NO   |     | Not Entered |                |
| mileage_units     | enum('mls','kms')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | NO   |     | mls         |                |
| num_doors         | varchar(25)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NO   |     | Not Entered |                |
| num_owners        | int(2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| engine_size       | varchar(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| transmission_type | enum('Manual','Automatic')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NO   |     | Manual      |                |
| body_type         | enum('Saloon','Hatchback')                                                                                                                                                                                                              | NO   |     | Saloon      |                |
| condition         | varchar(75)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NO   |     | NA          |                |
| extra_features    | text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| tax_expiry        | varchar(7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| nct_expiry        | varchar(7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| variation         | text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| tax_class         | enum('Agricultural','Bus') | NO   |     | Private     |                |
| co2               | int(9)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM concept_development WHERE NAME LIKE 'autos'

```
+-------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
| Name  | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options                                  | Comment |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
| autos | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 196168 |            136 |    26804224 |               0 |     26279936 | 340787200 |         485405 | 2010-09-17 22:09:45 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL | checksum=1 delay_key_write=1 row_format=DYNAMIC |         |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

show indexes from autos;

```
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| autos |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id              | A         |      294937 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| autos |          1 | ad_id           |            1 | ad_id           | A         |      294937 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| autos |          1 | style_id        |            1 | style_id        | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| autos |          1 | manufacturer_id |            1 | manufacturer_id | A         |         194 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| autos |          1 | model_id        |            1 | model_id        | A         |         830 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Is `models.name` indexed too?

Comment: Just added it, same problem though :-(

Comment: I know this might be a pain to do but we really do need more information to help solve this. Please look here http://pastie.org/1221602

Comment: can you include explain ads; show indexes from ads; explain autos; and show indexes from autos. you can just pastie the results if you prefer to keep your question from growing too large

Comment: thanks fOO, really lost on this one! :-)

Comment: models.id is int(11), but autos.model_id is int(10).  It may have trouble using the indices if they are different types.

Comment: Greg, thanks for that - I updated the autos.model_id field but same issue is still happening.

Comment: @Jason quick question - i would have thought that a user would register a vehicle (auto) on the system and then create an advert for that vehicle. If that vehicle failed to sell in the specified period the owner may decide to pay for another advert for that vehicle so the relationship between auto and advert is 1:M i.e. 1 vehicle could have MANY adverts ??? If so, where's the auto_id in the advert table ??

Comment: @fOO - In the application auto is a subclass of ad, so during the ad placement process the user starts off placing an ad, then once they select any auto category the auto model is created. There are other tables such as pets, property, jobs for other "types" of ad. Does this make sense?

Comment: sure - thanks, just getting a feel for the model, will have an in depth look shortly

Comment: I sure do appreciate your help!, if anything does not make sense just let me know :-)

Comment: hey, sorry for the delay bit busy this end and now i've just noticed the time 1:34am lol. i've had a quick stab at this, have a look at what i've done or what i'm attempting to do at least here. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/275658/ I'll pick it up again tomorrow morning with a fresh head :)

Comment: @gregcase: int(10) and int(11) are internally identical in MySQL. the parenthesized number just refers to how many digits are displayed in output. Internally they're both normal 32bit-sized ints.

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL documentation:

```
Temporary tables can be created under conditions such as these:
    * If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or if the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: Oh, and the file sort could be from the ORDER BY clause, and not having an index on models.name

Comment: Is there a way to re-write this then so it does not crate the tmp table? I've added an index on models.name just now

Comment: I could try playing around with some different indexes, but I'd need to see the table schemas. Try using "SHOW CREATE TABLE models;" (Repeat for the other 2 tables also). That makes it easier for me to recreate the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Change all the text columns to varchar.  If you need to maintain them as "text", you'll need to snowflake the schema and exclude the description tables from this query.

If any of the columns in any of the tables are text or blob, MySQL automatically creates an on-disk temporary table, rather than an in-memory temporary table.  The temporary table itself isn't killing you, it's the fact that it's writing it to the disk.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

> Some conditions prevent the use of an in-memory temporary table, in which case the server uses an on-disk table instead:
>
> - Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table

Answer (score 0):

You have a index on pub_end_date, but not on pub_start_date and your WHERE clause references both.

It looks like it is not using the pub_end_date index, but this could be because it needs to check pub_start_date as well.

Comment: Hi Alan, Just added an index on pub_start_date - no joy I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

This isn't explaining *why* but how about you rewrite your query to not use a group by? I think you're just joining on those tables to ensure there exists an ad of interest. So how about:

```
SELECT `models`.* 
FROM `models` 
WHERE models.manufacturer_id = 50 
AND EXISTS (   SELECT * FROM `autos` 
               INNER JOIN `ads` ON  `ads`.id = `autos`.ad_id 
               WHERE autos.model_id = models.id 
               AND ads.ad_status_id = 4 
               AND ads.pub_start_date < NOW() 
               AND ads.pub_end_date > NOW() 
             )
ORDER BY models.name;
```

The performance issues *might* be related to the `group by`, in which case this would improve performance.

Maybe it'd look a bit nicer with `and NOW() between ads.pub_start_date and ads.pub_end_date`, if you're allowed to do that in mysql (and if it works how you want with the edge cases).